# What is the concept of specifiying same declarations multiple times in interface and classes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> I'm trying to learn to handle forms in typescript and React from this [blog](https://www.carlrippon.com/building-super-simple-react-form-component-typescript-basics/). React specifically for the first time.

I'm observing the following is the source of `Form.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IFormProps {
  /* The http path that the form will be posted to */
  action: string;
}

export interface IValues {
  /* Key value pairs for all the field values with key being the field name */
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface IErrors {
  /* The validation error messages for each field (key is the field name */
  [key: string]: string;
}

export interface IFormState {
  /* The field values */
  values: IValues;

  /* The field validation error messages */
  errors: IErrors;

  /* Whether the form has been successfully submitted */
  submitSuccess?: boolean;
}

export class Form extends React.Component<IFormProps, IFormState> {
  constructor(props: IFormProps) {
    super(props);

    const errors: IErrors = {};
    const values: IValues = {};
    this.state = {
      errors,
      values
    };
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether there are any errors in the errors object that is passed in
   * @param {IErrors} errors - The field errors
   */
  private haveErrors(errors: IErrors) {
    let haveError: boolean = false;
    Object.keys(errors).map((key: string) => {
      if (errors[key].length > 0) {
        haveError = true;
      }
    });
    return haveError;
  }

  /**
   * Handles form submission
   * @param {React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>} e - The form event
   */
  private handleSubmit = async (
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
  ): Promise<void> => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.validateForm()) {
      const submitSuccess: boolean = await this.submitForm();
      this.setState({ submitSuccess });
    }
  };

  /**
   * Executes the validation rules for all the fields on the form and sets the error state
   * @returns {boolean} - Whether the form is valid or not
   */
  private validateForm(): boolean {
    // TODO - validate form
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Submits the form to the http api
   * @returns {boolean} - Whether the form submission was successful or not
   */
  private async submitForm(): Promise<boolean> {
    // TODO - submit the form
    return true;
  }

  public render() {
    const { submitSuccess, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate={true}>
        <div className="container">
          {/* TODO - render fields */}
          <div className="form-group">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              disabled={this.haveErrors(errors)}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
          {submitSuccess && (
            <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">
              The form was successfully submitted!
            </div>
          )}
          {submitSuccess === false &&
            !this.haveErrors(errors) && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred
              </div>
            )}
          {submitSuccess === false &&
            this.haveErrors(errors) && (
              <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                Sorry, the form is invalid. Please review, adjust and try again
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The thing which I'm not understanding is that the `constructor` of class `Form` have

- `errors`
- `values`

And both of them could have been handled as simple arrays of objects but why there is so much of declaration? As I can see:

- `IValues`
- `IErrors`

to represent them...

I seek help to understand the concept behind this for all these extra declarations.

Comment: *both of them could have been handled as simple arrays of objects*: sure, but you would then have had a runtime error or strange behavior since the code expects them to be objects, not arrays. Specifying the type precisely allows avoiding this kind of error: if you try to initialize them with an array, you'll have a compile time error. If an online store accepts only Visa cards, it's easier for you if they clearly tell that on the payment page, rather than letting you try with a mastercard and get a hard to diagnose error. Same here: the interface avoids making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both of them could have been handled as simple arrays of objects

There's more than one way to handle things and the creator of the post has decided to handle things the following way. Whether it's the best way to handle things is up to you to decide. I can only explain the reasoning behind them.

```
export interface IValues {
  /* Key value pairs for all the field values with key being the field name */
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface IErrors {
  /* The validation error messages for each field (key is the field name */
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

The first interface(`IValues`) declares a contract where any object implementing it has to contain string keys coupled with a value of any type.

The second interface(`IErrors`) specifies a contract where any object implementing it has to contain string keys that point to string values.

This is the concept of a Key-Value pair also known as a hash, a dictionary, or a map depending on what languages you are familiar with.

Typescript actually has a built in type called `Record` which allows you to do the above without being nearly as verbose. It is defined as follows.

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = { [P in K]: T }
```

With this definition of Record, the interfaces can be constructed as,

```
type IValues = Record<string, any>
type IErrors = Record<string, string>
```

In fact, the interfaces can be totally replaced with Record types.

As for the rest of the code, it is quite obvious that this person may not be writing the most optimized nor the most concise, i.e the least vebose, code. For example:

```
  private haveErrors(errors: IErrors) {
    let haveError: boolean = false;
    Object.keys(errors).map((key: string) => {
      if (errors[key].length > 0) {
        haveError = true;
      }
    });
    return haveError;
  }
```

This check can be short-circuited to return true when the first error is encountered. By the way, this only checks for at least one error in a singular form, so it can be better named as `hasError` or `hasErrors`

```
  private hasError(errors: IErrors) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(errors))
     if (value)  // <---- if (value) alone is enough as an empty string '' is falsy
       return true;

   return false;
  }
```

The list of improvements that can be made go on, but it can be safely said that the blog in question might not be the foremost authority on TypeScript or JavaScript for that matter. Proceed with caution.

P.S.

```
{submitSuccess === false && ...} = {!submitSuccess && ...}
```

Why? `submitSuccess` is defined to be a boolean there is no need to [triple equals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using) it to false.

[Falsiness](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/falsy-values/)

Comment: I believe `interfaces` are more known and intuitive than `Record` and `hasError` is replaced correctly. The concept seems like we're trying to avoid errors on compile time than on run time

Comment: Agreed with the last sentence. As for the other one, Interfaces is where you start, but the true power of typescript is in it's type literals. I do understand the use of an interface though, it's more main-stream and beginner friendly. After all, types are documented in the advanced section of the handbook  
 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 1):

When you write to an interface, you are agreeing to a contract: the form of the interface is guaranteed at compile time to be the form of the data.

When you pass around bare data structures, you have no such guarantee: the data you are given may have more or less than you imagined it would, and the only way to verify is by runtime checks. Those are more expensive than compile time checks.

Comment: Thank you but I'm unable to relate. Can you please relate with examples so I can connect my neural network... Sorry for my noobness :(